MongoDB Community Kubernetes Operator - Arbiter PVC

Arbiters are mongod instances that are part of a replica set but do not hold data

But the operator still create Persistent Volume Claims (data-volume-mongodb-arb-0) that hold the same amount of data as normal replicas. Is it normal behavior or not?
I use both a default configuration and a configuration with volumeClaimTemplates to replicate the issue:
---
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  members: 2
  arbiters: 1
  type: ReplicaSet
...

